# Refreshing a ListFragment with a LoaderManager

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListFragment class as a subclass of my activity and in my `PreferenceActivity` I have a setting to change the sorting of 2 out of the 5 possible list views I have but when I return back to the activity with the listviews the `onCreateLoader` does not get called again so the list remains the same.

How can I update the list after changing the settings value?

an example of my `onCreateLoader`

```
if(pref.getString(Preferences.CAL_SORT, "1").equals("1")){
                return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),CalendarEvents.EVENTS_URI,
                        new String[] {CalendarEvents.EVENT_ID,CalendarEvents.EVENT_READ,CalendarEvents.EVENT_SUBJECT,
                            CalendarEvents.EVENT_COMPANY_NAME,CalendarEvents.EVENT_START}
                        ,null,null,CalendarEvents.EVENT_COMPANY_NAME+" COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC," /*+ julianday("*/+CalendarEvents.EVENT_START/* + ")"*/ + " COLLATE LOCALIZED DESC");
            }else{
                return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),CalendarEvents.EVENTS_URI,
                        new String[] {CalendarEvents.EVENT_ID,CalendarEvents.EVENT_READ,CalendarEvents.EVENT_SUBJECT,
                            CalendarEvents.EVENT_COMPANY_NAME,CalendarEvents.EVENT_START}
                        ,null,null,CalendarEvents.EVENT_COMPANY_NAME+" COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC," /*+ julianday("*/+CalendarEvents.EVENT_START/* + ")"*/ + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
            }
```

I know I can call `notifyDatasetChange()` on the adapter but the adapter is not visible to the outer activity. Should I do something in my `ContentProvider`

This is how my class is structured

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static class ListViews extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0,Bundle arg1){
        }
    }

    public void onResume(){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call [getLoaderManager().restartLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderCallbacks)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#restartLoader%28int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E%29). In `onCreateLoader()` you can create  new `Loader` based on the supplied `Bundle`.

See sample at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html how it is used when the filter changes. For detecting preference changes you can use [SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html).

Comment: ok I am a bit confused where I should be using this, I figured that in my `onResume` on my activity i could refresh the list after returning from the PreferenceActivity but the `getLoaderManager` is not visible in my outer `MainActivity`. That example only shows using that inside of the class that has a loader

Comment: `Fragment`s have also `onResume()` method. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onResume%28%29. Override it and call it there.